# Class instantiation when several values/string are involved

Tags: c#

When we write code like the one given below (in the console Main), Are we, in fact, instantiating the employee class? The employee class contains get and set for serial no, name, and a List for job title and constructor as well.

```
List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
employee.Add(new Employee(1,"Thomas Alva Edison",new string[]{"Inventor"}));
```

My question is it like the basic instantiation as below.

```
Employee e1=new Employee(1,"Thomas Alva Edison",new string[]{"Inventor"}))
```

Comment: Yes it is ..... they are both calling same constructor. second one is storing the result in `e1` variable. but first one is passing it as argument to the `Add` method.

Comment: The code is identical in both cases, so the result is the same. A new `Employee` instance is created. It doesn't matter where references of that instance are stored, eg in the variable `e1` or inside a list. Every call to `new` create a new object instance

Comment: Thanks so much to both M.kazem Akhgary and Panagiotis Kanavos. But I was wondering till yesterday, that the with instantiation taught in books like the 2nd one, how we could add large amounts of data. It is only today I understood it better.

Comment: Now if after adding several such items, what is the appropriate method to call a Method in the Employee class to display the items in the Employee List. What I have done now is using a foreach to loop through the Employee list and call the method Display. Is it right? @ M.kazem Akhgary @Panagiotis Kanavos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code1 :

```
employees.Add(new Employee(1,"Thomas Alva Edison",new string[]{"Inventor"}));
```

We instantiate employee, do not save reference to it but add it to collection.

Code2 :

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(1,"Thomas Alva Edison",new string[]{"Inventor"});
```

We instantiate employee the same way but store reference to it in `e1` variable.

With code2 you can still add it to collection via reference :

```
employees.Add(e1);
```

You can also access object inside your list by index or using LINQ :

```
var e = employees[0];
var e = employees.First();
```

It's also possible to fill collection with values using collection initializer :

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
{
   new Employee(1,"Thomas Alva Edison",new string[]{"Inventor"})),
   new Employee(2,"Kazem Zooo Benson",new string[]{"Inventor"})),
   new Employee(3,"Mike Oslo Jameson",new string[]{"Inventor"}))
};
```

Sometimes it's more convenient to use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` collection rather then `List<T>`.

Let's assume that we are working with `List<Employee>` from last example and we want to get only employee with first name "Mike".
With `List<T>` we have to use `LINQ` or `foreach` to iterate the entire collection to find what we are looking for :

```
Employee mike = employees.First(e => e.Name.StartsWith("Mike"));
```

So it's kind of cumbersome. We can use dictionary to store names as a keys :

```
Dictionary<string, Employee> employees = new Dictionary<string, Employee>()
{
   {"Thomas", new Employee(1,"Thomas Alva Edison",new string[]{"Inventor"})},
   {"Kazem", new Employee(2,"Kazem Zooo Benson",new string[]{"Inventor"})},
   {"Mike", new Employee(3,"Mike Oslo Jameson",new string[]{"Inventor"})}
};
```

In this scenario if we want to get Person named Mike we only need to access the key of our dictionary:

```
Employee mike = employees["Mike"];
```

Comment: Your answers to my simple question has tremendously improved my knowledge concerning this aspect of which I was ignorant all these days. I have no words to thank you all.

Comment: Is there a way to programatically create such references like e1, e2, e3 etc.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan no, normally you cannot dynamically create variables. What you can do is you can use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` collection. I've updated my answer to cover the scenario

Comment: I presume instead of the List<employee>, you are suggesting that a Dictionary as shown above will be rather excellent. Thank you so much. @Fabjan

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Well, In simple scenarios where you just need to store range of ints (for instance) using of `List<int>` might be a better idea but with class like `Person`, you'd most likely want to map your person to one of its properties (or fields) like Id, Name or any other. In this case   `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is exactly what you need. Although it takes more time to initialize and Dictionary is more complicated, it is considerably faster when it comes to accessing elements by index.

Comment: This is Great knowledge. Thanks @Fabjan

Comment: If my last query is not out of place here, would you just show how to call this List<employee> for displaying the contents of the list in the class Employee. What I did presently is to use a foreach on Employee list in the main and called a method Display in the class. Is there any other way? @Fabjan

Comment: @Unnikrishnan We've gone away far enough from your initial question. Ask your new question in a separate post (including your code and your problem) and then we'll sort it out.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I appreciate it

Answer (score 5):

As far as instantiation, they are the same.  They both create one instance of the Employee class.  But they are different in that the object handle for the first is stored in the first item of a list, while the handle for the second is stored in a single object pointer.  Just depends on what you want to do with it.  If you are going to have more items in the list, i.e. process multiple employees' information, then the first might make sense, but if you are only going to process one employee, then the second probably makes more sense.

Comment: I am amazed. Wonderful answers. I did not understand this so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the constructor, however `employee` is a list of employees.

You can't call `employee.Name` without getting the reference from the list.

```
List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
employee.Add(new Employee(1,"Thomas Alva Edison",new string[]{"Inventor"}));
Employee e1 = employee[0];
```